# Building a validation set from a train set

Tags: python, validation, pandas, dataframe, training-data

I have a training dataframe with equal number of labels from each class. The classes are labeled [-1,0,1,2,3]. I want to build a validation set which is  20% the size of training set such that I have equal number of labels in each class in the validation set too. I wrote the following code. train_data_frame.stage has the labels [-1,0,1,2,3] :

```
total_stages_set = set(train_data_frame.stage)
minimum_samples = round(len(train_data_frame['stage'])/4 * 0.2)
validation_frames = [train_data_frame[train_data_frame.stage == s].sample(n=minimum_samples, replace=False) for s in total_stages_set]
validation_frame = pd.concat(validation_frames)
```

This gives me my validation set. The problem is I want to remove these rows from my train_data_frame. I tried using row indices but turns out they are not unique hence that removes unwanted rows. Any suggestions? I don't mind scrapping out this code if there is another idea.

Comment: Try using the [test_train_split](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) function in sklearn.  Just set your dependent as 'y' and the rest as 'X'.  It'll be cleaner :).

Comment: But does train_test_split split equally among all label classes? or is it random?

Comment: Good point.  It is random and looks like it's not what you want.  The argument for random sampling is that the train set would be best the data set. Nonetheless,  resetting the index of train_data_frame (using reset_index()) so that the row indices are unique before your sampling logic is a potential solution.  Should you want to keep the row indices, then save them in a dummy column while you do your sampling (i.e. train_data_frame['old_ind'] = train_data_frame.index... reset_index() ... **do your magic**... then validation_frame.index = validation_frame['old_ind'])